# Convergence of trigonometric infinity series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I need to know if this series converges and if so, to which value.  The series is given by:

\begin{equation}
M_2(X) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{12m}{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}{\frac{(x_{i}^2 + x_{i}x_{{i+1}} + x_{{i+1}}^2)(x_{i}y_{{i+1}} - x_{{i+1}}y_{i})}{\pi r^2}}}
\end{equation}

I thought to transform it in polar coordinates
$$x = c_1 + r\cos(2\pi i/N)$$
$$ x = c_2 + r\sin(2\pi i/N)$$
Where ($c_1, c_2$) is a center and $i$ and $N$ are natural numbers. This equation is from a polygon with $N$ sides.

In polar co-ordinates the equation above is

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}
\sum_{i = 1}^{N}
((\alpha^2
+\alpha\beta
+\beta^2)(\alpha\gamma
-\beta\gamma))
$$

Where $\alpha=(c_1+r\cos(\frac{2\pi i}{N}))$
$\beta=(c_1+r\cos(\frac{2\pi (i+1)}{N}))$ $\gamma=(c_2+r\sin(\frac{2\pi (i+1)}{N}))$

Comment: Where did this come from? Is it a Fourier Series or did you make it up or what.

Comment: I edited the expression and I put more information.